# Laravel 8 serve my Tailwind CSS file in HTML tags

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to apply Tailwind into a fresh Laravel installation. I've followed the documentation on both sites [Tailwind: Install with Laravel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel) and [Laravel: Tailwind CSS](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#tailwindcss)

My configuration is like this.

**/tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
     './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**/resources/css/app.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**/webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

**/resources/views/welcome.blade.php**

```
// Calling the stylesheet like this
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**The Problem**
When I'm trying to view the source of my CSS files, it's inside HTML tags and not the raw CSS code.

**view-source:https://example.com/css/app.css**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
    <style>
    // CSS code is here
    </style>
    ....
</html>
```

**Question**
Any tips on why the CSS file is not served correctly and how I can fix this?

Comment: I understand that the content of `https://example.com/css/app.css` is the same as your index and contains `<html lang...>...` Is that right? How do you access your app? `nginx`, `apache` `php artisan serve` .. ? Also, only to be certain; does `/yourproject/public/css/app.css` contains your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of searching wildly I found that the following command was the solution, it just seemed strange to me that it wasnt mentioned on the official docs of laravel or tailwind.

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Now the CSS is served normally.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm run production` when you go live. [Read more how to prepare for production.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production)